# FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I am trying to learn how to connect a Next.js project with Firebase.

I have this code in the config.js file:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
...

};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore();

export { auth, db };
```

Actually I had that mistake with other code, so I found an answer in stack overflow to the same problem, and now I have this code and still doesn't work and I don't know why.

The previous version was:

```
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
...

};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);  
}else {
  firebase.app(); // if already initialized, use that one 
}  

export default firebase
```

This is what I have in the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "events_app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "firebase": "^9.19.1",
    "next": "13.2.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^5.1.1",
    "reactstrap": "^9.1.9",
    "sass": "^1.60.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3"
  }
}
```

And this is auth.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

import { getAuth
    , signOut
    , onAuthStateChanged
    , signInWithEmailAndPassword
    , createUserWithEmailAndPassword  
} from "firebase/auth";

const registrerWithEmail = async (email, password) => {
    const auth = getAuth(); 
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((userCredential) => { 
        const user = userCredential.user;  
          
        return { user }
    }).catch((error) => { 
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;  
        return { 
            error: errorCode + ': ' + errorMessage
        }
    })

}

const signWithEmail = async (signInEmail, signInPassword) => { 
    const auth = getAuth();
    
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, signInEmail, signInPassword)
    .then((userCredential) => {  
        const user = userCredential.user; 
        return { user }
    }).catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log('Error: ', errorCode + ': ' + errorMessage) 
        return { 
            error: errorCode + ': ' + errorMessage
        }
    })
}

const signOutUser = async () => {  
    const auth = getAuth();
    return signOut(auth).then(() => { 
        return {
            suscess: true
        }
      }).catch((error) => { 
        return {
          error
        }
      })
}

const authState = async (userFnc) => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, userFnc); 
}

const getCurrentUser = () => { 
    const auth = getAuth();
    const user = auth.currentUser; 
    return user 
 }

export default { 
    registrerWithEmail,
    signWithEmail,
    signOutUser,
    getCurrentUser,
    authState
}
```

I hope someone be able to help me.
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Please add more details about what is not working: error message, npm package that is used and its version, code where requests are made to Firebase.

Comment: Hi @ArturA, I just added all the details. Thanks.

Comment: Also try to use `getAuth()` inside `useEffect`, so that Next.JS will follow Client Side Rendering instead of Server Side Rendering.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no need to mix imports of the `compat` version with the modern NPM `firebase` package. [Compat](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) was specifically created to support the old import style.  Please remove all imports of `firebase/compat/*`. Just use direct modular imports from `firebase/auth`, `firebase/app`, `firebase/firestore`.
2. The updated code in `config.js` looks good:

   ```
   import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
   const firebaseConfig = {
   ...

   };

   export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
   export const auth = getAuth(app);
   ```

   That config.js should be either:
   a) (Recommended) Imported at the root of the React, inside `index.js` or `App.js` file, e.g.:

   ```
   import * from './path-to/firebase/config.js';

   export const App = () => {
     //...
   }
   ```

   Then it will be possible to call `getAuth()` anywhere in the application without parameters, the default instance of `app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` will be automatically used.

   b) Without importing firebase initialization at the React root (`index.js` or `App.js`), there is a need to specify which FirebaseApp and Firebase Auth instances to use. Thus, you need to import everywhere initialized `auth` from config.js`, like:

   ```
    // notice the Firebase Auth was initialized as `getAuth(app)` inside config.js, below it is reused:
   import { auth } from './path-to/firebase/config.js';

   const authState = async (userFnc) => {
      onAuthStateChanged(auth, userFnc); 
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi @Artur, I couldnt work on this project last days. I am trying to follow your answer, but I have a problem. When I use your code in config, I got this error: getAuth is not defined. I just did: import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
const firebaseConfig = {
...

};

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);

Comment: Besides that, in app.js I did: import * as config from '../firebase/config'; but then, I don't know who to use it. I mean how I include it in the rest of the code in app.js

Comment: Hey @NicoBonder, just add `import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';` to your file.
For global usage, by default `app.js` is the root file for React application, so anything imported in that files becomes kind of a `global import` for whole applications.